# large __getitem__ overhead when accessing internal dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, overhead

I have the following map class that uses a dictionary as it's base data structure:

```
class Map:

''' A map object to handle the game world
'''

    def __init__(self, initial_grid=None, rooms=None, default=None):

        self.grid = initial_grid
        if not self.grid:
            self.grid = {}

        self.default = default
```

And it has an access method that tries to get the info from it's grid, but if it can't returns the default argument

```
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.grid.get(key, self.default)
```

Now in another part of my code, I have this function running a very large number of time, giving me the following cProfile results:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

2510000    0.739    0.000    0.926    0.000 map.py:57(__getitem_ _)

2510001    0.187    0.000    0.187    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
```

If I understand it correctly, most of the time in the function (~80%) is not spent on retrieving the value, so what actually happens in all that time? Any way of improving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of dict getting involved: `self.grid` is a `__getitem(…)`, which gets the grid from the self-dict, then `self.grid.get` is another one, finally `self.default` gets the `default` entry from self.

To reduce the number of `get`s, you may want to add the following to your class:

```
__slots__ = ('grid', 'default') # add whatever field you have
```

This should speed up your code considerably, because slot access is reduced to a simple array access.

Comment: hmm, I tried adding that and don't see any noticeable difference, does it change the item access because from what I read it only limits the total amount of variables to save space. Also correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't '{method 'get' of 'dict' objects}' already include these internal calls in map.py? I don't see anything else that could fit them though